Gap on the right in <span>, looks like an extra space at the end
So I was adding a button to my website as a test and it made me notice my all my spans have a gap on the right like theres an extra space at the end, and by adding a background box to it it became very noticeable. I looked over all my other pages and sure enough its there too. I dont have anything that modifies it as far as I can tell so I dont know whats making it happen and figured Id see if anyone else knows whats going on. If youd like to check it out for yourself my website sebringautomotivellc.com has the problem live on it right now, thats my test site before I make changes. Also here are some screenshots of the problem and the code css code html code chrome webtools


#website.css
main::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
a {
}
p {
    max-width: min(90%, 1000px);
    margin: 2vw auto;
    font-size: min(4.5vw, 25px);
    font-family: avenir;
}
h1 {
    
}
h2 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: min(7vw, 35px);
    color: #555555;
    padding: 1vh 3vh;
    margin: 0 auto 3vh;
    display: inline-flex;
}
hr {
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin: 4.5vh auto -4.5vh;
    width: 99%;
    height: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: avenirlight, sans-serif;
}
header {
    height: 30vh;
    background: #353738;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: sticky;
    top: -17vh;
}
header > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
a > picture > img {
    height: 15vh;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}
a > h1 {
    margin: -1vh 0 1vh;
    font-size: min(4vh, 10vw);
}
nav {
    background-color: #999999;
    font-size: min(4vw, 2vh);
}
nav > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin: auto min(1vw, 1vh);
    padding: 1vh;
    background-color: #504e4e;
}
nav > a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
main {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
}
.spanbg {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(50vw + 18vh);
    min-height: calc(50vh + 18vh);
    max-height: calc(70vh + 18vh);
    margin-top: 12.5vh;
}
.spanbg > picture > img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.span {
    height: 50vw;
    min-height: 50vh;
    max-height: 70vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;
}
.span > span {
    font-family: luloclean;
    font-size: 8vmin;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 3vmin;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.bg {
    background: url('../pics/sunsetbg.webp') center, url('../pics/sunsetbg.jpg') center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 5vw 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
.bg > div {
    padding: 2.5vw 10vw;
}
.autoformat {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5vw;
}
@media (min-width: 100vh) {
    .autoformat {
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    }
}

#projects.css
.autoformat > picture > img {
    background-color: Grey;
    padding: 5%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 85%;
}
.autoformat > picture:nth-child(4n + 2) > img {
    background-color: Red;
}
.autoformat > picture:nth-child(4n + 3) > img {
    background-color: White;
}
.autoformat > picture:nth-child(4n) > img {
    background-color: Black;
}
span > a {
    font-size: 3vmin;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #444444aa;
    padding: 2vmin;
}
span > a:hover {
    color: #999999;
    background-color: #00000000;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/website.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/projects.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="spanbg">
        <picture>
            <img src="pics/lineup.jpg">
        </picture>
    </div>
    <header>
        <a href="home"><picture>
            <img src="pics/frontlogo.jpg" alt="Logo AW11 Front">
        </picture></a>
        <a href="home"><h1>Sebring Automotive</h1></a>
        <nav>
            <a href="home">Home</a>
            <a href="services">Services</a>
            <a href="projects">Our Projects</a>
            <a href="contact">Find Us</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="span">
            <span>Our Cars</span>
            <span><a href="customers.html">Customer Cars</span>
        </section>
        <section class="bg">
            <div class="autoformat">
                <picture>
                    <source type="image/webp" srcset="pics/pilot.webp">
                    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="pics/pilot.jpg">
                    <img src="pics/pilot.jpg" alt="Jack Locke's 2014 Honda Pilot Limited">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source type="image/webp" srcset="pics/dragstrippt.webp">
                    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="pics/dragstrippt.jpg">
                    <img src="pics/dragstrippt.jpg" alt="Kyle Sebring's 1989 AW11 Toyota MR2 Supercharged">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source type="image/webp" srcset="pics/tundra.webp">
                    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="pics/tundra.jpg">
                    <img src="pics/tundra.jpg" alt="Wayne Sebring's 2012 Toyota Tundra Supercharged">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source type="image/webp" srcset="pics/tortamobile.webp">
                    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="pics/tortamobile.jpg">
                    <img src="pics/tortamobile.jpg" alt="Carlos Rincon's 2005 E46 BMW 330i ZHP">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>




The issue is related to letter-spacing, as you can see in this snippet. It’s been a known issue for ages.


body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 3vmin;
}

.s2 {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.s2 span {
  letter-spacing: unset;
}
<section class="s1">
  <span>Our Cars</span>
</section>

<section class="s2">
  <span>Our Cars</span>
</section>



The issue has been discussed by the CSS standards group, and they agreed that the spec is correct (extra spacing should only be added between letters) but that browser implementations are all incorrect. The availability of workarounds is also discussed – adding extra left padding or a negative right margin.


body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 3vmin;
}

.s2 {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.s2 span {
  padding-left: 3vmin;
}
<section class="s1">
  <span>Our Cars</span>
</section>

<section class="s2">
  <span>Our Cars</span>
</section>




Ah I see, well good to know its not a problem with my code but thats still unfortunate to hear. What are your thoughts on finding a way to extend the main body then centering the text instead of using margin or padding, or is that too difficult?

My first choice would be extra left padding, as demonstrated in the second snippet. Seems like it should work in your scenario.

Thanks for the info, thats what I ended up doing and it works great!
